# Find the matrix of the given linear transformation $T$ with respect to a given basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you solve $T (f(t)) = f(2t - 1)$ from $P_2$ to $P_2$, with respect to basis $\beta = (1, t-1, (t-1)^2)$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you solved any problem related to your question before?

Answer (score 0):

Given basis $\beta = (1, t-1, (t-1)^2)$ and $T (f(t)) = f(2t - 1)$. Take $f(t)=1$ then $f(2t-1)=1$, hence $T(f(t))=1$. Next take $f(t)=t-1$ then $f(2t-1)=2t-1-1=2t-2=2(t-1)$. Hence $T(t-1)=2(t-1)$. Similarly $T((t-1)^2)=4(t-1)^2$, Now form the matrix.

> the matrix will be $diag\{1,2,4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$T$ maps back to the same source, thus $\beta$ is a suitable basis to chose for the transformation matrix. The transformation matrix is nothing more than coordinate column vectors of $T$ to some basis, in this case $\beta$.

What happens to each basis element of $\beta$ under $T$?

**Hint**: $T(\beta_1) = 1 = 1\beta_1 + 0\beta_2 + 0\beta_3$
So the first column of $[T]_{\beta}^{\beta}$ will be... $[1, 0, 0]^T$

The rest follow accordingly.